# \StrLeft has no effect on \citetitle

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, strings

`\footfullcite` uses too much space so I decided to define a own command. I called it `\footshortcite`. It only display a pre- and a post-Option and the Author with Year. However, I don't like that most citations in the footnote by my new command only use 1/4 or 1/3 of the line length, so I had the idea to put  the title of the citation on top and cut it after X characters so that the footnote-citation is round about one complete line length.

I tried it with `xstring` but it seems that `\citetitle` is not fully expandable, so that `\StrLeft` has no effect on it.

Did I something wrong or am I right and its not possible?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur.bib}

@BOOK{denz2005,
author = {Denz, Hermann},
title = {Grundlagen einer empirischen Soziologie: Der Beitrag des quantitativen
Ansatzes},
publisher = {Lit},
location = {M\"unster},
year = {2005}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}                

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\usepackage{optparams}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\footshortciteintern[#1][#2]#3{%
\ifx#1\empty 
% Nur Autor
\footnote{\citeauthor{#3}, \citeyear{#3}.}
\else
\ifx#2\empty
% Autor und Seite
\footnote{\citeauthor{#3}, \citeyear{#3}, #1.}
\else
% Autor, Seite und vgl.
\expandafter  
\footnote{#1 \citeauthor{#3}, \StrLeft{\citetitle{#3}}{10}, \citeyear{#3}, #2.}
\fi
\fi
}
\newcommand*\footshortcite{%
\optparams{\footshortciteintern}{[\empty][\empty]}
}

\begin{document}

Hallo \footshortcite[vgl.][S.111]{denz2005}
%\footshortcite[S.111]{denz2005}
%\footshortcite{denz2005}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is `biblatex`'s `\DeclareCiteCommand`. It enables you to easily pass bibliographic data to `xstring`, format titles according to entry type and define multicite versions of new citation commands.

Truncation of titles may not work well in general (see the image below). I've added an alternative that makes use of the `shorttitle` entry field.

The only `xstring` macro used here is `StrLeft`, so details on how this code works can be found in the `biblatex` manual.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\foottrunccite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:trunc}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:trunc}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}}
                {\printnames{labelname}%
                    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
            \iffieldundef{title}
                {}
                {\addcomma\addspace%
                    \printtext[citetitle]{\StrLeft{\thefield{labeltitle}}{10}}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footshortcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}}
                {\printnames{labelname}%
                    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
            \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
                {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
                {\printfield[citetitle]{shorttitle}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footshortcites}[\mkbibfootnote]%
    {\footshortcite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\foottrunccites}[\mkbibfootnote]%
    {\foottrunccite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{denz2005,
    author = {Denz, Hermann},
    title = {Grundlagen einer empirischen Soziologie: Der Beitrag des quantitativen Ansatzes},
    shorttitle = {Grundlagen einer empirischen Soziologie},
    publisher = {Lit},
    location = {M\"unster},
    year = {2005}}
@ARTICLE{angenendt,
  author = {Angenendt, Arnold},
  title = {In Honore Salvatoris~-- Vom Sinn und Unsinn der Patrozinienkunde},
  shorttitle = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
  volume = {97},
  date = {2002},
  pages = {431--456}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Vanilla footcite.\footcite[vgl.][111]{denz2005}
Vanilla footcites.\footcites[vgl.][111]{denz2005}[456]{angenendt}
Like footcite, but with short title.\footshortcite[vgl.][111]{denz2005}
Like footcites, but with short title.\footshortcites[vgl.][111]{denz2005}[456]{angenendt}
Like footcite, but with truncated title.\foottrunccite[vgl.][111]{denz2005}
Like footcites, but with truncated title.\foottrunccites[vgl.][111]{denz2005}[456]{angenendt}
\end{document}
```

[image]